# creating dictionary with ansible

Tags: loops, dictionary, ansible

I want to create a dictionary in ansible from a list; using some variables for the value in the key-value pair of the dictionary, but it seems to be not working.

I've simplified just to the problem and created a sample playbook to reproduce the issue, can someone help me out. Thanks!

here is my playbook

```
---
- name: create dictionary test
  hosts: all
  connection: local
  gather_facts: False

  vars:
    ports: [80, 443]
    server_base: "org.com"

  tasks:
    - name: print the ports
      debug:
        msg: "ports: {{ports}}"

    - name: create a dictionary
      set_fact:
        #server_rules: "{{server_rules|default([]) + [{'server': '{{server_base}}-{{item}}', 'port': item}]}}"
        server_rules: "{{server_rules|default([]) + [{'server': '{{server_base}}', 'port': item}]}}"
      loop: "{{ports|flatten(1)}}"

    - name: output
      debug:
        msg: "server_rules: {{server_rules}}"
```

With the above it works, the output as below:

```
$ansible-playbook -i "localhost," dicttest.yaml

PLAY [create dictionary test] ***************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [print the ports] **********************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "ports: [80, 443]"
}

TASK [create a dictionary] ******************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=80)
ok: [localhost] => (item=443)

TASK [output] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "server_rules: [{'server': 'org.com', 'port': 80}, {'server': 'org.com', 'port': 443}]"
}

PLAY RECAP **********************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

But when I change set fact to (uncomment the one commented line and comment the other one)

```
server_rules: "{{server_rules|default([]) + [{'server': '{{server_base}}-{{item}}', 'port': item}]}}"
```

it fails with the following error

```
$ansible-playbook -i "localhost," dicttest.yaml

PLAY [create dictionary test] ***************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [print the ports] **********************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "ports: [80, 443]"
}

TASK [create a dictionary] ******************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=80)
ok: [localhost] => (item=443)

TASK [output] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'item' is undefined\n\nThe error appears to be in '/Users/dev/dicttest.yaml': line 22, column 7, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n    - name: output\n      ^ here\n"}

PLAY RECAP **********************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Can someone explain how to get this working.

Answer (score 3):

Q: ***Given the data***

```yaml
  ports: [80, 443]
  server_base: org.com
```

***create a list of dictionaries***

```yaml
  server_rules:
  - port: 80
    server: org.com-80
  - port: 443
    server: org.com-443
```

A: The task below gives the expected result

```yaml
    - name: create a list of dictionaries
      set_fact:
        server_rules: "{{ server_rules|default([]) +
                          [{'server': server_base  + '-' + item|string,
                            'port': item}] }}"
      loop: "{{ ports }}"
```

---

It's not necessary to iterate the list in a task. The declaration of the variables below does the same job

```yaml
  servers: "{{ [server_base]|
               product(ports)|
               map('join', '-')|
               map('community.general.dict_kv', 'server')|
               list }}"
  server_rules: "{{ servers|
                    zip(ports|map('community.general.dict_kv', 'port'))|
                    map('combine')|
                    list }}"
```

---

Notes:

- Double braces "{{ }}" can't be nested. The expression below is wrong

```yaml
      "{{ var1 + ['{{server_base}}-'] }}"
```

Correct

```yaml
      "{{ var1 + [server_base + '-'] }}"
```

In YAML, the operator plus "+" is used both to concatenate strings and lists. This is because a string in YAML is technically a list of characters. It's recommended to use "~" to concatenate strings

Also correct

```yaml
      "{{ var1 + [server_base ~ '-'] }}"
```

- Use *var* attribute in *debug*. The output is more readable with *stdout_callback = yaml*

```yaml
    - debug:
        var: server_rules
```

- The created variable *server_rules* is a list. The items are dictionaries. Hence, it's a list of dictionaries.
- The variable *ports* is a simple list. There is no need to use the filter *flatten*.
- The combination of "*hosts: all*" and "*connection: local*" would make to run all hosts at the localhost

```yaml
  hosts: all
  connection: local
```

Use "*hosts: localhost*" if you want to run the playbook at the localhost. In this case "*connection: local*" is the default

```yaml
  hosts: localhost
```

If you want to run a task at the localhost, but still want the play to read the variables for all hosts, use "*delegate_to: localhost*" and limit the task to "*run_once: true*". For example

```yaml
  - hosts: all
    tasks:
      - copy:
          content: "{{ ansible_play_hosts|to_nice_yaml }}"
          dest: /tmp/ansible_play_hosts.yml
        delegate_to: localhost
        run_once: true
```

Comment: Thank you, very helpful and a lot of learning here, much appreciate your sincere feedback and answer.

Answer (score 0):

got an answer from another person outside of stackoverflow, posting here just to make sure anyone looking at this, gets the solution as well

changing as follows fixes the problem

```
server_rules: "{{server_rules|default([]) + [{'server': '{{server_base}}-' + item|string, 'port': item}]}}"
```

The complete working playbook

```
---
- name: create dictionary test
  hosts: all
  connection: local
  gather_facts: False

  vars:
    ports: [80, 443]
    server_base: "org.com"

  tasks:
    - name: print the ports
      debug:
        msg: "ports: {{ports}}"

    - name: create a dictionary
      set_fact:
        server_rules: "{{server_rules|default([]) + [{'server': '{{server_base}}-' + item|string, 'port': item}]}}"
      loop: "{{ports|flatten(1)}}"

    - name: output
      debug:
        msg: "server_rules: {{server_rules}}"
```